# lat, long based search with $near shutdown my mongodb on Linux server

Tags: mongodb, linux

Hey guys i am stuck on critical problem & unable to resolve it. I have a project where there is a collection of UK postcodes having 18,00,000 sample postcode records. I have a search query where i am doing a latlong search with $near within 15000 metre area to retrieve postcodes associated with that latlongs.

My query is here.

```
$mongoPostcode = MongoDbConnector::getCollection("postcodes");
$postcodeData = $mongoPostcode->findOne(array('postcode' => $postcode, 'activestatus' => 1)); //

$latitude = '';
$longitude = '';

$latitude = $postcodeData['latitude'];
$longitude = $postcodeData['longitude'];

$query = array('geometry' =>
    array("\$near" =>
        array("\$geometry" =>
            array('type' => 'Point',
                'coordinates' => array(floatval($latitude),  floatval($longitude))
            ),
            "\$maxDistance" => 15000
        )
    )
);

$mongoPostcode->ensureIndex(array("geometry" => "2dsphere"));
$nearByPostcodeData = $mongoPostcode->find($query);
```

I ran & tested the query & it worked successfully on my localhost. When i uploaded it on server & did the search, I stopped unexpectedly. When i checked for the server logs it has showed me this.

```
2016-02-26T13:59:59.880-0500 I INDEX    [initandlisten] found 1 index(es) that wasn't finished before shutdown
2016-02-26T13:59:59.882-0500 I INDEX    [initandlisten] found 1 interrupted index build(s) on GoTutor.postcodes
2016-02-26T13:59:59.882-0500 I INDEX    [initandlisten] note: restart the server with --noIndexBuildRetry to skip index rebuilds
2016-02-26T13:59:59.885-0500 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: GoTutor.postcodes properties: { v: 1, key: { geometry: "2dsphere" }, name: "geometry_2dsphere", ns: "teachme.postcodes", 2dsphereIndexVersion: 2 }
2016-02-26T13:59:59.885-0500 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method
2016-02-26T14:00:02.015-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 75300/1812402 4%
2016-02-26T14:00:05.005-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 283200/1812402 15%
2016-02-26T14:00:08.005-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 484500/1812402 26%
2016-02-26T14:00:11.005-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 684500/1812402 37%
2016-02-26T14:00:14.005-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 813000/1812402 44%
2016-02-26T14:00:17.004-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 1078500/1812402 59%
2016-02-26T14:00:20.005-0500 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 1282300/1812402 70%
2016-02-26T14:00:21.179-0500 F -        [initandlisten] out of memory.

 0xf81182 0xf80c99 0xf018b1 0xaad617 0xaaeada 0xa92b48 0x931c3d 0x932df6  0xab7764 0x80bc25 0x7d8619 0x7f3492863ec5 0x8085ec
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B81182"},{"b":"400000","o":"B80C99"},
{"b":"400000","o":"B018B1"},{"b":"400000","o":"6AD617"},
{"b":"400000","o":"6AEADA"},{"b":"400000","o":"692B48"},    
{"b":"400000","o":"531C3D"},{"b":"400000","o":"532DF6"},    
{"b":"400000","o":"6B7764"},{"b":"400000","o":"40BC25"},    
{"b":"400000","o":"3D8619"},{"b":"7F3492842000","o":"21EC5"},   
{"b":"400000","o":"4085EC"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.8", "gitVersion" : "83d8cc25e00e42856924d84e220fbe4a839e605d", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.13.0-57-generic", "version" : "#95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "01C2B48B0D634DE2288131FFED72B73D35289E15" }, { "b" : "7FFF1EA6D000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1C0D0A18FF043EED9EE11DB5E5E90A3F74729341" }, { "b" : "7F3493E6D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9318E8AF0BFBE444731BB0461202EF57F7C39542" }, { "b" : "7F3493C0E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D08DD65F97859C71BB2CBBF1043BD968EFE18AAD" }, { "b" : "7F3493833000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F86FA9FB4ECEB4E06B40DBDF761A4172B70A4229" }, { "b" : "7F349362B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92FCF41EFE012D6186E31A59AD05BDBB487769AB" }, { "b" : "7F3493427000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C1AE4CB7195D337A77A3C689051DABAA3980CA0C" }, { "b" : "7F3493123000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4BF6F7ADD8244AD86008E6BF40D90F8873892197" }, { "b" : "7F3492E1D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D76B71E905CB867B27CEF230FCB20F01A3178F5" }, { "b" : "7F3492C07000", "path" : 
 ........
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0xf81182]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo29reportOutOfMemoryErrorAndExitEv+0x49) [0xf80c99]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoMallocEm+0x21) [0xf018b1]
 mongod(+0x6AD617) [0xaad617]
 .......
 mongod(main+0x159) [0x7d8619]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7f3492863ec5]
 mongod(+0x4085EC) [0x8085ec]
 -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Thing is now i am not able to start my mongodb, even if i start it then it is not connected & i can't see any database. I tried even to reboot the system. And then tried to connect to mongodb from desktop GUI Umongo still it refuses the connection.

I am not able to get what is happening here!. How to recover my server to its previous state & what is the solution to my search query in order to allow it to  run smoothly?

Any help would be appreciable always.

Comment: Have you read the message carefully? E.g. have you tried "restart the server with --noIndexBuildRetry to skip index rebuilds"? There's also "out of memory" indicator. Have you tried adding more swap?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but on server side i am working on deployment with such a huge data for the first time. So it is new for me.

Comment: out of memory i knew about but u said about swap. I didnt get it. what exactly i have to do?

Comment: Most interesting that you think this "worked successfully" when the order is meant to be "longitude then latitude" ( see [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) ) for both all MongoDB geospatial queries as well as being the [GeoJSON standard](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions). But this is of course a server configuration issue and not a programming question.

Comment: it worked on my localhost & not on server. Its right u said. Long needs to be first & lat second.

Comment: but what do i have to do recover my server's previous state with mongodb running? coz it is not working anymore

Comment: Add more swap. Create a large file somewhere using `dd`, format it using `mkswap` and then add using `swapon`: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/

Comment: @nsilent22 Which is a horrible idea.  A loopback file is dependent on the underlying filesystem (have fun with atime and mtime!), making it extremely slow unless you know what you are doing – in which case creating a swap partition is not much of a problem.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Who was talking about loopback file? Just make swap in the file. There will be no performance loss unless your filesystem is very fragmented: http://serverfault.com/questions/25653/swap-partition-vs-file-for-performance

Comment: @nsilent22 You. Because the swapfile you proposed will be mounted loopback.

Comment: @nsilent22 But in general: Swapping MongoDB gives _horrible_ performance. A far better idea would be to add more RAM. If the RAM can't hold the indices, the working set and potentially the WT cache, writing the entries manually to paper is most likely the faster alternative ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: No, my friend. As far as i know swap in swapfile does NOT use any loopback devices. And of course idea 'add more RAM' is very good, as good as 'use better computer'.

Answer (score 0):

About

> what is the solution to my search query in order to allow it to run
>   smoothly?

The server may be imposing memory limitations, so while indexing the collection memory limit would have been crossed. If that is the case then you cannot index it all at once, but you can first index the collection and add data to it consecutively.  If I were you,

- I would delete the collection on the server first.
- Then I would recreate the collection and
- index the 'empty collection' as 2d or 2dsphere.
- After that I would copy the data into the collection batch by batch
  programaticaly so that out of memory issue will not probably occur.

You may write a script that reads 1000 rows at a time from your local DB and saves it as bulk into your remote DB.

Another solution is(Only my guessing, I have not tried it or studies it) to make a backup of already indexed collection of local DB and restore it into the remote DB. I am not sure about this approach, only a guess.